# Buddhist cannon database

Tags: reference-request, sutras, abhidhamma

s there an online database that either contains the Buddhist canon in either English or Chinese?

I've had a difficult time tracking down first hand sources other than the usual suspects (Heart Sutra, Prajnaparamita sutra, etc). I've been looking for anything related to pratityasamutpada in the abhidharma, but I don't even know where to look, or even if English translations exist.

Does anyone know where to look?

Answer (score 1):

There are several large scholarly collections you can access freely:

Organizations:
[International Association of Buddhist Studies](http://www.iabsinfo.net/)

Sanskrit:
[Digital Sanskrit Buddhist Canon](http://www.dsbcproject.org/)

Chinese:
[WWW Database of Chinese Buddhist texts](http://www.kanji.zinbun.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~wittern/can/can4/ind/canwww.htm)
[Digital Database of Buddhist Tripitaka Catalogues](http://jinglu.cbeta.org/index_e.htm)

Japanese:
[The SAT Daizōkyō Text Database](http://21dzk.l.u-tokyo.ac.jp/SAT/index_en.html)

English:
[English Translation of the Buddhist Canon and Publication Project](http://www.bdk.or.jp/english/english_tripitaka/publication_project.html)

hope this helps